# Notice: Array to string conversion. without array in code

Tags: php, mysql

**the problem=**
in my code i get the id of a person out of the database, then i fetch it and then i put it on another table in the database.
so first this i get the id out of the database:

```
$patientid = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id FROM patient WHERE     `naam` = '$naam' AND `adres` = '$adres'");
```

then i fetch it:

```
$patientid1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($patientid);
```

then i put it in another table:

```
$toevoegen = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO factuur (`soort`, `hoelang`, `titel`, `omschrijving`, `datum_aangemaaktfactuur`, `patient_id`, `artsid`)
        VALUES ('$soort', '$hoelang', '$titel', '$omschrijving', '$datum', '$patientid1', '$artsid1')");
```

then when i run the code i get this notice: Notice: Array to string conversion.
how do i solve this? i have looked at other questions but they have the same error but different code. i dont even have an array in my code!
thanks

ps:  if i replace $patientid1 with an number it works perfectly.

Comment: you need to use `$patientid1['id']`

Comment: Please don't use this code at all. It is wide open for all kind of sql-Injections.

Comment: @Oliver i'm new to this, we will learn how to program safe in the next year.

Comment: @NiekBrouwer if this code never comes live, everything is fine. Just keep it in mind :-)

Comment: *"we will learn how to program safe in the next year"* - It might be too late by then; do it now while you still have a database to work with.

Comment: Its a school project so it wont come live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array with selected fields as keys and column values as values.

You should modify code as follows

```
$patientRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($patientid);
$patientId = $patientRow['id'];
```

Remember that for non unique results, you should iterate over whole result set like

```
while ($patientRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($patientid)) {
    $patientId = $patientRow['id'];
    // other actions here
}
```

Last but not least, pay attention to `$naam` and `$naam`: use [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead will be definitely safer